# case on join criteria possible

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my query:

```
select
    case when m.current0 < 25000 then 'Limited' else 'Unlimited' end,
    m.current0 as CurrentBalance,
    m.status as CurrentStatus,
    sh.datechanged as EntertedPA6,
    datediff(d, sh.datechanged, getdate()) as DaysPassed 
from StatusHistory sh
inner join master m 
  on m.number = sh.accountid 
  and sh.newstatus = 'pa6' 
  and sh.datechanged <= DATEADD(day, -20, GETDATE()) 
  and m.status = 'pa6' 
  and m.state = 'ca'
```

Similar to the case statement in the first line of the select.  I need something similar on the join criteria.

```
If m.current0 < 25000 then sh.datechanged <= DATEADD(day, -20, GETDATE())
If m.current0 > 25000 then sh.datechanged <= DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE())
```

Is this possible or do I need to do a union all?

Comment: You can just use an `OR` like `(m.current0 < 25000 AND sh.datechanged <= DATEADD(day, -20, GETDATE())) OR (m.current0 > 25000 AND sh.datechanged <= DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE()))`.

Comment: @user2989408 Adding this seemed to create a loop in the join.  instead of pulling back the 197 rows.  It pulled back over 1.7 million before i stopped it.

Comment: You could add that to the `WHERE` clause. Moreover adding everything to the JOIN clause is not a good practice.

Comment: And just a thing that i saw now. What about the m.current0 is exactly equals to 25000. You are not considering this. :)

Comment: @JorgeCampos good point.  I will fix that. :)

Comment: From a parser point of view, conditions in the JOIN clause are 100% equivalent to conditions in the WHERE clause. The only reason you can say it is not good practice is that it makes the statement less readable to human programmers.

Comment: @JamesWilson that was because I forgot to add braces to enclose the whole thing. Fixed it in the answer.

Comment: @RossPresser Wanted to add that they are the same only when the JOIN is an INNER JOIN, in case of `OUTER JOIN`s its not the same.

Comment: You're correct, of course, @user2989408.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ORs and ANDs you could do something like

```
select
    case when m.current0 < 25000 then 'Limited' else 'Unlimited' end
    ,m.current0 as CurrentBalance
    ,m.status as CurrentStatus
    ,sh.datechanged as EntertedPA6
    ,datediff(d, sh.datechanged, getdate()) as DaysPassed 
from StatusHistory sh
    inner join master m on m.number = sh.accountid and sh.newstatus = m.status           
WHERE m.status = 'pa6' AND m.state = 'ca' AND
    ((m.current0 < 25000 AND sh.datechanged <= DATEADD(day, -20, GETDATE()))
     OR (m.current0 >= 25000 AND sh.datechanged <= DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE())))
```